# Django Admin - display 3 different unrelated models on one view using Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

So, I am re-making a website for a company and have to use all of their existing databases on my website.  I have been using Django and am now to the admin side of things.  This is my basic problem:

I have three types of orders (meaning that each type of order is a different type of service so the orders all have different fields from each other), for simplicity I will call them order1, order2 and order3.  They are not connected through foreign keys at all.  I currently have three different admin classes for each order type and am doing

```
admin.site.register(Order1, Order1Admin)
admin.site.register(Order2, Order2Admin)
admin.site.register(Order3, Order3Admin)
```

which is making the correct admin page for each model.  However, a requirement given to me is that these three order types must all be listed on the same page.  So basically I need to display these three order types side by side on the same page and still maintain the ability to sort by date, I have been looking all over and have found things like inlines, but like I said these have no foreign keys connecting them to the other.  How would I do something like

```
admin.site.register(Order1, Order2, Order3, OrderAdmin)
```

Are there any options within Django admin for allowing something like this?  If not, where is a good starting point to figure out how to make a custom view for these three orders but still have it be within the Django admin framework?

Comment: How do these objects differ?

Comment: Each order is a different type of service with different fields.